# How to get the element with name="ab" and value="xy"? Is it possible with querySelector, or are there other and faster ways?

Tags: javascript, performance, css-selectors, radio-button, selectors-api

So I have in the html-code the radio button
`<input type="radio" name="ab" value="xy">`

How could I get the element by using javascript, using for example 
`var el = document.querySelector( ... )` ?

Is that possible? Or is there a faster way because querySelector might be slow?

Background: I'm using Javascript to change the selected input of many radio sets, and I want to establish a takeback function by storing the name and value of the previously checked inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute value selectors.

```
document.querySelector("input[name=ab][value=xy]");
```

And for better performance, select from a container within the document, perhaps the `form` element that the input is in.

Comment: Great answer! I haven't tested it yet, but that's exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't figure out in the definitions I found about the selectors how to write that selector. Now I just wonder, often those document dom-tree functions aren't the fastest: Are there different, but faster ways?

Comment: @John: I wouldn't worry about its performance unless it's proving to be an issue, which doesn't seem likely. As I noted, if you select from a container that you have a reference to, you'll get better performance: `myFormElem.querySelector(...)`.

Comment: While you are here, allow me a follow up question, please: The different radio sets currently are named in the style `[unknown number]ForAb`. Could I use some sort of match-function in the querySelector, like in a regex or simply `*ForAb` to get all radio sets I'm looking for? (Currently I just use `getElementsByTagName('input')` and iterate over the resulting array.)

Comment: There are several attribute selectors you can use. One of them lets you select by the value's ending. `[name$=ForAb]`

Comment: Thank you very much for both solutions, you just reduced the number of code lines from like 30 to 10 for me.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped.